# WSO2 ESB and REST services security

Tags: rest, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have a couple of backend REST services which I have to use through the WSO2 ESB. I use basic authorization header for the backend. I've created the service in ESB and it works fine when I call it through the firefox RESTClient plugin. Here's the configuration:

```
<proxy name="ADocumentLibraryAuth" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('xxx:xxx'))" scope="transport"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint name="test">
                    <address uri="http://xxxxxx:8080/alfresco/s/slingshot/datalists/lists/xx/xx/xx"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Now I want to secure this service through the ESB (for example using the usernameToken security). I can easily enable this, but I don't know how I can call/use this service. Should I generate wsdl client for this and call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the proxy services you are creating are SOAP services, hence when you add any type of WS-Security, you can invoke it by generating the clients using the WSDL. The WSDL has the applied sec policy attached to it.

Regards,
/Nuwan

Comment: I've tried securing the service above using the usernameToken policy. However I can still make a call to the service without applying the security header. Is there any example of exposing a REST service through ESB with security enabled? My backend service also uses JSON objects could this be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have few options,
  Like either to use proxy as REST adapter, but it has minimum features init, but you can easily integrate your REST EP with the REST API element, which gives you the possibility of integrating  security scenario ref [1], and if you need to find out more information regarding the capabilities of REST API please refer [2]

[1] http://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/apply-oauth2-0-base-security-for-rest-endpoint-with-wso2esb-4-6-0-and-wso2is-4-1-1-alpha/

[2] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/REST+Support